# Class methods undefined for Instance when class is exported from file

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a class `BinarySearchTree` in a file (`a.js`) which I've exported then imported `BinarySearchTree` in other file and use it as a parent class for one of other class `Traversal`.
The issue, I felt is that the method present in the parent class is not accessible in the child class (throws error as :

> error TS2339: Property 'getRootNode' does not exist on type
>   'Traversal'.

Note: I tried keeping both the class in the same file and it works without error.

I'm new to Typescript but well versed with ES Standards. Please highlight, If i'm missing any details here or if there is a work around.

Code Segment: 
**a.ts**

```
export class BinarySearchTree 
{
    root: any; 
    constructor() 
    { 
        // root of a binary seach tree 
        this.root = null; 
    } 

    getRootNode() 
    { 
        return this.root; 
    }
}
```

**b.ts**

```
import { BinarySearchTree } from './a.ts';

export class Traversal extends BinarySearchTree{
    constructor() 
    { 
        super()
    } 
}

var _traversal = new Traversal();
_traversal.getRootNode()
```

Comment: Please show the failing code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 constructor() {
    this.data = 123;
    this.testMethod = this.testMethod.bind(this);
   }

   testMethod() {
      console.log('test')
   }
```

Now you have access to testMethod() of this class.

As you can see I just created a property instance named `testMethod` which represents `testMethod()` in the current class. Since `this` pointer refers to encapsulated class that is why you can access to its members.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly now